# Send Blob to server with Axios, receiving an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, blob

I am trying to send an audio as a Blob object in React with Typescript to the server with Axios. I have been trying many ways but I always get an emty object on the node server.

As I have seen, now I have what it should be the correct way to do it. But still get an empty object.

```
const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}'
    }
  };

  try {
    var formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('audio', audioBlob);

    const res = await axios.post('/api/recording', formData, config);
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data.errors);
  }
```

If i do

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

and send a normal json for example

```
{ test: 'test' }
```

I do receive it correctly on the server.

Comment: How do you try to get the form-data in your node?

Comment: I am just printing console.log(req.body) and I get {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are sending the data in `multipart`, you need to listen to the `data` event to get the body data. If I am sending `{foo: bar}` as data, I can get it like:

```
app.use ( '/foo', ( req, res ) => {    
    req.on ( 'data', ( data ) => {
        console.log ( data.toString () );
    } );

    req.on('end', () => {
        res.send('ok');
    });
} );
```

However, this will give you something like this:

```
----------------------------807095611705406533847525
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

bar
----------------------------807095611705406533847525--
```

This would be difficult to parse. So to ease the parsing, you can use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). This would give you the data in your `req.body` object.

```
let multer           = require ( 'multer' );
let processMultipart = multer ( { storage : multer.memoryStorage () } );

app.use ( '/foo', processMultipart.array ( "foo" ), ( req, res ) => {
    console.log ( req.body );
    res.send ( "ok" );
} );
```

This would give you the output as `[Object: null prototype] { foo: 'bar' }`and you can access the value as `req.body.foo`.